# How to estimate a fixed effects regression WITH robust standard errors AND instrument variables

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, instrumental-variables, robust-standard-error

I have been trying to estimated the stated problem, but I only succeed in parts of it. The following artificial setup is supposed to illustrate my problem in detail:

Setup the data:

```
library(plm)
data(Cigar)
```

Fixed effects AND robust standard errors  (works perfectly)

```
  fit <- plm(price ~ sales + pop, data=Cigar, index=c("state","year"), model="within")

> coeftest(fit, vcov.=vcovHC(fit))

t test of coefficients:

        Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
sales -1.0391141  0.1671141 -6.2180 6.726e-10 ***
pop    0.0190151  0.0064447  2.9505  0.003228 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

New Fixed effects regression WITH Instruments: (sales is instrumented with cpi)...

```
fit <- plm(price ~ sales + pop | cpi + pop, data=Cigar, index=c("state","year"), model="within")
```

...renders usage of coeftest problematic!

> coeftest(fit, vcov.=vcovHC(fit))
>       Fehler in vcovG.plm(x, type = type, cluster = cluster, l = 0, inner = inner,  : 
>         Method not available for IV

Well the error message is obvious, but I am just wondering what other people do who face the same problem as I do?

I hope I don't miss something but there is no statistical reason why heteroskedasticity cannot apply in this setting, right?

So is there any possibility to estimate robust standard errors in this setting with the plm package or are there any R-packages which may help? 
Thank you very much for your answers - any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two `coef()` calls, so I suspect something is missing. In addition, questions about how to use software are usually off topic here (this strikes me as borderline), so you may want to try to bring the statistical issue to the fore & deemphasize the 'how do I do this in R' part.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. There has been a line drop during copy and paste from R, should be fixed now.

Comment: Your comment "but there is no statistical reason why heteroskedasticity cannot apply in this setting, right?" needs qualification. Do you expect the variance to be different for each cross-section? Time varying heteroskedasticity? Or do you anticipate each observation to have a different residual variance? You need an appropriate model of heteroskedasticity (and autocorrelation) that applies to your case. If it helps, note that Stata's [`xtivreg`](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/xtxtivreg.pdf) computes cluster robust standard errors when `robust` standard errors are requested (pg. 6).

Comment: The appropriate methods for robust vcovs were not implemented in plm. They are now in the development version >= 1.6-1 (see r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=406).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The methods are also in CRAN versions of plm >= 1.6-4.

The appropriate methods for robust vcovs were not implemented in plm. They are now in the development version >= 1.6-1 (see http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=406).

```
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
data(Cigar)
fit <- plm(price ~ sales + pop, data=Cigar, index=c("state","year"), model="within")
fit2 <- plm(price ~ sales + pop | cpi + pop, data=Cigar, index=c("state","year"), model="within")

coeftest(fit, vcov.=vcovHC(fit))

# t test of coefficients:
#
#
#         Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# sales -1.0391141  0.1671141 -6.2180 6.726e-10 ***
# pop    0.0190151  0.0064447  2.9505  0.003228 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

coeftest(fit2, vcov.=vcovHC(fit2))

# t test of coefficients:
#
#        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# sales -6.2479556  1.9032780 -3.2827 0.001055 **
# pop   -0.0021752  0.0121773 -0.1786 0.858260   
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```